# How to convert a grayscale image's black to alpha "correctly"?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I made a quick script to convert a grayscale image's black to alpha, and it looks like this:

```py
from PIL import Image

i = Image.open("glow.jpg")
new_i = i.convert("RGBA")
pxs = new_i.load()
# The original image's size is 1024x1024

for x in range(1024):
 for y in range(1024):
  pxs[x, y] = (255, 255, 255, pxs[x,y][0])

new_i.save("glow.png")
```

[image: The original one]

After executing the script i tried to blend the resulting png with a black background in GIMP, and it is different from the original one:

[image: The one the script generated blended with a black background in GIMP]

Is it a problem with GIMP? If not, how can I modify the code to make it blend correctly?